# Empty response in MEAN database query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get my Node.js server to communicate with a database so that I can extend it to an Angular front end. I have a path that makes a request to the database that should return the entire database (5 documents). I have a connection to the database as I can see it connect when I refresh the server.

I will try to list only the relevant code below:

Loading the modules...

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var app = express();
```

Defining the database schema and connecting

```
// Database connection and scheme ===================
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/data/');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    date: 'String',
    newProofs: [Number],
    changes: [Number],
    output: [Number]
});

var TEST2014 = mongoose.model('TEST2014', schema);
```

Middleware configurations. I don't know what methodOverride does. I believe the body parser allows the response to be JSON?

```
//  Application middleware and configurations ==============
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));                    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                                         // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));     // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
```

Path for making request to database.

```
app.get('/api/TEST2014', function(req, res) {

    // Use mongoose to get all weekdays for display
    TEST2014.find(function(err, days) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error then nothing else
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(days);
    });
});
```

Listening...

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

When I refresh the page at `http://localhost:3000/api/TEST2014` I see this:

```
{}
```

I expect to see this (what I currently have in the database).

```
> db.TEST2014.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("541c377d51b7f5ebbffb7ab1"),
        "date" : "09192014",
        "newProofs" : 15,
        "changes" : 16,
        "output" : 17
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("541c4a4451b7f5ebbffb7ab2"),
        "date" : "09182014",
        "newProofs" : 7,
        "changes" : 8,
        "output" : 9
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("541c4a5651b7f5ebbffb7ab3"),
        "date" : "09172014",
        "newProofs" : 8,
        "changes" : 9,
        "output" : 10
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("541c4a7151b7f5ebbffb7ab4"),
        "date" : "09162014",
        "newProofs" : 9,
        "changes" : 10,
        "output" : 11
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("541c4a8051b7f5ebbffb7ab5"),
        "date" : "09152014",
        "newProofs" : 10,
        "changes" : 11,
        "output" : 12
}
```

Thanks for reading!

PS - My request header says it accepts `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

Does JSON need to be somewhere in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remedy the problem by changing the mongoose connection to the following:

```
mongodb://<local ip>:27017/<database name>
```

Closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the following line:

```
var TEST2014 = mongoose.model('TEST2014', schema);
```

By default, when you pass only 2 arguments to the above function, mongoose assumes the collection name as being 'TEST2014s' that is first argument plus an "s".

I see in your query below that your collection name is 'TEST2014'. I would recommend you to explicitly pass the collection name and try the following instead:

```
var TEST2014 = mongoose.model('TEST2014', schema, 'TEST2014');
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am still receiving the same result. I don't fully understand what you mean. Why would it add an "s?" I tried to find the documentation but I can't find anything that lists the acceptable parameters.

Comment: It is just a convention used by Mongoose. Here is an excerpt of the documentation:    _When no `collection` argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by passing the model `name` to the [utils.toCollectionName](#utils_exports.toCollectionName) method. This method pluralizes the name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option._